# What can you use WebDriver Actions Chains for?

Tags: webdriver

I have:

- Keyboard "chords", e.g. Ctrl + typing
- Copy and pasting (e.g. Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V)
- Drag and drop
- Drag by N pixels
- Mouse hovering
- Right mouse click
- Drawing on a canvas

What else can you do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not you take a look into the methods [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)? As far as I can see you already have mentioned important ones. You also can do pause, release, move to the middle and offset of element, keyup, keydown and context click etc.